# AWS log grouping by request

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-app-engine, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I recently migrated from Google App Engine to AWS Fargate, and one feature that seems to be lacking is that GAE grouped logs that matched a given inbound request ID, and had an easy to navigate UI wherein:

1. You see a list log groups, one for each inbound HTTP call (e.g. `GET /items`)
2. On clicking one of these groups, you see a list of all GAE logs that pertain to that request, ordered by timestamp, starting from when the request was received by GAE to when the response was sent back

I'm struggling to find an equivalent function in AWS. Is there one? How does one set something similar up?

Comment: You can try to query / view the logs using Cloudwatch Log Insights. At least that enables you to view logs across different log streams within the same (or multiple) log groups. Additionally Xray *may* be useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are options, but nothing exactly like what you're used to from Google App Engine, no.

[AWS X-Ray](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/index.html) is perhaps the AWS Service that is closest to the kind of functionality you're talking about, but it's really meant to help you trace a request across multiple microservices or from your code to Amazon services and back, which is a more complicated use case than what you're describing.

X-Ray uses an `X-Amzn-Trace-Id` header, and [AWS Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-request-tracing.html) can do the same, so if you're happy with that trace id, that might be relatively easy to adopt. If you're not using a load balancer or you would rather use a different format, there's no reason you can't use a correlation id from a framework in your development platform or even something custom to your application, particularly if you don't need the X-Ray features. I have clients with microservices that use custom correlation ids.

You can include those request / correlation identifiers in plain or structured logging that you send to CloudWatch, and once you've done so, you can then filter your CloudWatch logs on those identifiers. With those custom correlation ids above, that's what ops staff do when they want to follow a request in CloudWatch logs.

So ... is there an option 'for free' like there seems to be in GAE? No. Can you get most of that capability back with a little work if you feel so inclined? Sure.

Comment: Thanks! Structured logging is the way we're aiming to do it for now, but that StackDriver request->logs UI will sorely be missed

Comment: Yeah, sounds nice -- I've cobbled together similar solutions for my own use (custom correlation ids, logging, using `awslogs` cli with `--filter` parameter), but having it built-in would definitely be nicer. Although I think you're more likely to find that with an integrated PaaS solution like GAE, and AWS tends to stick more strongly to SaaS.